# Free file sharing service with command line client (Windows, Linux)

Tags: file-sharing

I need a free file sharing service that provides:

1. Command line-driven client utility that uploads/downloads/synchronizes files.
2. Windows & Linux client.
3. Read-only access for unauthorized users, i.e. free public access to some/all files.
4. Each file uploaded should have its own link and be accessible via this link over HTTP.
5. (Optionally) Support of file versioning.
6. 1Gb of space or more.

Do you know any?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

kliplink.com

You can post with the Linux utility:

./kl post -f

Which will give you an alias, then get it with:

./kl get -a

Files are limited to 5 a day of up to 10MB each.

Answer (score -1):

You should use https://github.com/